# How to get ETH from Dwarfpool to Coinbase?

Tags: ether, metamask, coinbase

I have been mining Ethereum (ETH) using SMOS and Dwarfpool for the last few months.  I was also using MetaMask to transfer my mined ETH coins to Coinbase.  It was working fine until MetaMask pushed an update this week, and now all my account balances and history in their interface have been completely wiped out.  I'm familiar with their process for regenerating an account with a seed phrase, as I've had to do that a couple times to access my accounts on MetaMask through my various computers.

My question isn't about MetaMask, so much as it is about how can I can get my mined ETH coins over to Coinbase.  I've been working on this all evening, and I'm really stuck.  My confidence in MetaMask is somewhat diminished, so if there's another reliable way to do this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mined ETH was sent to your Metamask account, then you will need access to the Metamask account again to then transfer them to Coinbase.

If the issues you are facing are specifically around the latest update of Metamask, you should be able to download an older version through GitHub, and try installing that manually into your browser.

You can find every version which has been released here:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases

Comment: I logged into MetaMask from my work computer this morning, just for kicks, and amazingly my balance was back.  I transferred the vast majority out; I'll wait to see if the very small amount I left in the account is accessible from my other machines at home tonight, before restoring power to my rigs.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give it a try, if I have any other problems tonight.